# CakePHP - Change the "name" attribute of a form input

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a helper which generates a custom form input.

**Helper** (simplifed code)

```
public function customInput($field, array $options = array()) {

    $defaultOptions = array(
        'class' => 'custom-input',
        'label' => false
    );
    $options = array_merge($defaultOptions, $options);

    return $this->Form->input($field, $options);
}
```

Now how can I modify the name attribute of the input by prefixing it with another 'model'.  For example, the input will by default have the following name attribute:

```
<input type="text" name="data[MyModel][field]" />
```

But I want it to be:

```
<input type="text" name="data[_custom][MyModel][field]" />
```

Mainly, what seems tricky is that I don't know how to get the model name that will be used by default.  Also, I need something that works if the default model hierarchy is more complicated, like:

```
<input type="text" name="data[MyModel][AssociatedModel][field]" />
```

Would need to be modified to:

```
<input type="text" name="data[_custom][MyModel][AssociatedModel][field]" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `input` helper, CakePHP uses `$this->model()` to get the name of the current model.

You can see it inside `lib\Cake\view\FormHelper`, or directly from the online API: 
http://api20.cakephp.org/view_source/form-helper#line-942

```
$modelKey = $this->model();
```

Maybe that helps.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, as it seems to be the only thing I can use to generate the name dynamically but even then I think it will fall down if there is anything other than a basic Model.field key.  Model.Model.field or Model.0.field won't be possible I guess.

Answer (score 2):

You want `name`

```
echo $this->Form->input('whatever', array('name' => 'data[_custom][MyModel][field]'));
```

There is nothing like `data[_custom][MyModel][AssociatedModel][field]` in cakes form helper. Your options as far as automation go is:

- `field` // normal, use current model
- `Model.field` // used with not default model / relations
- `Model.$i.field` // User hasMany Post would be `Post.$i.field`

Answer (score 0):

well you can do:  `$this->Form->input('_custom.MyModel.field');` to create an input in the format you require.

It becomes a case of passing the appropriate model name and associated model with it.

I don't know how you could do this automatically as obviously each relation is different/may have multiple associations.

So using your helper: `echo $this->YourHelper->CustomInput('_custom.MyModel.MyAssociation.field', $options)` might do the trick.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't work because I don't know the model name of the form that will be using the Helper.  It could be any model name.  So the question really is how does the `Form::input()` method generate the name field itself.